# Non null assertion operator not working in new Angular Library project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-package-format

I created a new Angular library project with this code.

```
/**
 * Extract the path from the URL.
 *
 * @param url The URL to extract the path from
 */
 export function urlPath(url: string): string {
    return url!.match(/.*?(?=[?;#]|$)/)[0];
}
```

And even though I have a non null assertion operator `!` appending `url` I still get lint errors saying that `url` might be null ( Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531) ).

Any ideas?

This is the output from the build:

```
✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
projects/fs-validatorts/src/lib/utilities/url/urlPath.ts:7:12 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

7     return url!.match(/.*?(?=[?;#]|$)/)[0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong place:

```
return url.match(/.*?(?=[?;#]|$)/)![0];
```

You want to assert that there will always be a match.